# JQuery Code modification needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to tweek some functionality a bit.

Right now I am using this code in a JS file:

```
$('body').ready(function() { self.open(); });
```

I have some links from Page A to page B.

I basically want this popup ONLY to open if it's coming from one of these link on page A

Is that tweek possible please?

Comment: lollololl - this site is about learning - not about getting others t do your work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean

```
if (document.referer && document.referer.indexOf('pageA')!=-1) {
  window.open('somelink.html','_blank');
}
```

Comment: if that is a correct answer, then you aren't using jQuery Mobile Framework properly or at all

Comment: @Naugtur - and why is that? My suggestion is replacing the `self.open();` statement only

Comment: jquery mobile framework overrides all links with AJAX calls and appends fetched content to current page. referer won't work

Comment: If that is the case, the referrer (if sent) can be obtained before you load the framworks and stored in a global var, no? Anyway, that would be links and this is not a link but a window.open